# How to use dynamic component loader to instantiate a child component on a click?

Tags: dynamic, angular, modal-dialog, components, loader

I am using angular2.0.0-beta.15. Basically I am trying to load a modal window on click of a button in header. I have put template for modal in an html.What I am trying is, on click of button in parent component, a parameter which indicates which button is pressed, is passed to child component. Based on that I am getting data of modal from db and putting that in modal window.Below is the piece of code.

**parent.html**

```
<modal-child id="ContactModal"></modal-child>
   <-- code goes here-->
<li [style.display]="!showContact?'none':'inherit'"><a (click)="getContact()" data-remote="false"
                        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ContactModal"><i class="fa fa-question"></i>Contact</a></li>
 <-- code goes here-->
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input, provide, DynamicComponentLoader, Injector} from 'angular2/core';
 import {ModalChildComponent} from './modal.child.component';
 export class ParentComponent{
  private id: string;
 constructor(private dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, private injector: Injector) {}
   getContact() {
    this.id = 'Contact';
    this.dcl.loadAsRoot(ModalChildComponent, '#ContactModal', this.injector);
}
  }
```

**modal.child.component**

```
 import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';
 import {UserService} from '../services/data-services.service';
@Component({
selector: 'modal-child',
templateUrl: './views/templates/modalTemplate.html'
})
export class ModalComponent {
    @Input('id') modalId: string;
    private contactData: string;
  constructor(private _dataService: DataService) {
  console.log('id:' + this.modalId);
  if (this.modalId === 'Contact') {
      this.getContactData();
     }
  }
  getContactData() {
    this._dataService.getContact().subscribe(data => {
        console.log('contact:' + data);
        this.contactData = data;
    });
}
}
```

**modalTemplate.html**

```
<!-- Contact -->
 <div id="ContactModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Contact</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div [innerHTML]="contactData"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When i try above code, it gives me exception like 'Unexpected directive value '[object Object]' on the View of component 'ParentComponent'. Can somebody guide me?

Comment: this is solved by myself.

Comment: hello, how did you solved this problem please ?

Comment: yea. how did you solve?

Comment: sorry, I couldn't help you as I am unable to recollect what was the above scenario exactly and how i solved.